# Cake server not running

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am a novice and tried running the bookmarker tutorial from cakephp cookbook but it is showing the following error:

```
theclownprince@theclownprince-K53SM:~/bookmarker/bin$ cake server
Error: Class ServerShell could not be loaded.
```

If it try running it from bookmarker folder it showing a different error

```
theclownprince@theclownprince-K53SM:~/bookmarker$ bin/cake server
PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/theclownprince/bookmarker/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/theclownprince/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/theclownprince/bookmarker/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/theclownprince/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php on line 3
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you didn't run `composer install` yet. If you did, try re-creating the autoloader by running `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: I did run composer install first and then got mbstring and intl package. But it is not showing all the files it should be showing from the example in cookbook.  The files below are missing                                                                               .editorconfig
.gitignore
.htaccess
.travis.yml

Comment: I deleted the app and installed it again. Works now.